# How do I access my text file from other methods if it is passed as a command line argument in the main method(java)

Tags: java, methods, command-line, text-files, stdin

I am new to using multiple methods in Java so I am struggling quite a bit with this. I am using the stdIn library and the location of the text file is passed as a command line argument in the main method as follows: `In in = new In(args[0]);`. 
How do I read this file from another method and what method do I use? I am not quite sure how to access it from other methods as it keeps saying variables of type "In" are not allowed.

this is the code I have done so far

```
public class Practice {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        In in = new In(args[0]); // define the local variable
        abc(in);                 // pass it to the method
    }

    public static void abc(In in) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String s = in.readAll();     // use the method parameter
        double[][] boxes = readFile(s);

        System.out.println(boxes);
    }

    public static double[][] readFile(String s) throws FileNotFoundException {      
        File f = new File(s);
        Scanner scF = new Scanner(f);
        int R = scF.nextInt();
        int C = scF.nextInt();
        double[][] boxes = new double[R][C];
        while (scF.hasNextLine()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < C; j++) {
                    boxes[i][j] = scF.nextInt();
                } //reads file and adds values to a double[][] array            
            }               
        }
        return boxes;
        //returns a double[][] array 
    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It has to be of type 'In'

Comment: "it keeps saying variables of type "In" are not allowed" Do you mean you're getting an error from the compiler? Could you copy and paste the error and the code that produces it.

Comment: No, it just has the red cross on the left of the line where I try create a new method. So I have the `In in = new In(args[0]);` has described above in the main method. And then when I want to create a method to read the file, I call the method: public static double[][] readFile(In in) throws FileNotFoundException {   But it doesnt let me use the type "in" so I am not sure how else to access by args[o] from another method